# How to convert CIM_DATETIME format that obtained using WMI Queries into local time in C++(MFC/Win32)

Tags: datetime, winapi, mfc, wmi

I am creating a windows application in C++ to obtain system boot time.
I got that using wmi query ,but it is in the format "20140408141835.999999+480".
I need to convert it into %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S format.
I know in C# we have ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(); method.
But I need a solution in C++.

Comment: Did you tried to feed that number into COleDateTime constructor ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=vs-2019#coledatetime Once you have there, you can setup any format of your date time through they methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SWbemDateTime object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemdatetime) as explained here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121102-00/?p=6183

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
BOOL FileTimeFromCIMDateTime(__in LPCWSTR psz, __out LPFILETIME pft)
{
 BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;
 ISWbemDateTime *pDateTime;
 HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SWbemDateTime), 0,
                 CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDateTime));
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
  BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(psz);
  if (bstr) {
   hr = pDateTime->put_Value(bstr);
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    BSTR bstrFT;
    hr = pDateTime->GetFileTime(VARIANT_FALSE, &bstrFT);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
     __int64 i64FT = _wtoi64(bstrFT);
     pft->dwLowDateTime = LODWORD(i64FT);
     pft->dwHighDateTime = HIDWORD(i64FT);
     fSuccess = TRUE;
     SysFreeString(bstrFT);
    }
   }
   SysFreeString(bstr);
  }
  pDateTime->Release();
 }
 return fSuccess;
}
```

Another solution is to port the .NET source to C++, since .NET is open source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Management/ManagementDatetime.cs,45057a40319a1c83